# Bootstrap <div> error when I run AngularJS/nodejs project

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, bootstrap-4

When I run the project to see the login / register screen, it shows this screen

Login / register:

[image: login / register]

In my code I have Bootstrap, jQuery already declared

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
```

and I have the login/register in a div like this

```
<div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="!identity">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Identificate</h1>
        <form class="col-md-10">
          <p>
              <label>Correo electrónico:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required/>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Correo electrónico:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required/>
            </p>

            <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Registrate</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to see in the screen, to the left "Ingresa" and right "Registrate"

In the Chrome command line, I see this error:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js
>   (https://popper.js.org)
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: Did you read the error you got? `Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js`? Did you do something with that?

Comment: https://popper.js.org/ Chk this

Comment: @Dekel yes, I tried but the problem continue, so I delete it, for the post, I think someone know about it

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the entire block (from `<div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="!identity">` in a

`<div class="container-fluid" id="someContainer">`

Also, you need to read the bootstrap getting started a bit better - 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

It says you need to load popper js.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- load popper before BS ---> 
             <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- now load Bootstrap -->
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
             <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
```

See if that works...

Comment: I delete popper and popper declaration because it send me an error when i'm working with the project, an error with "index.d.ts" so I delete it hehe

Comment: mm the problem with index.d.ts yes lol but in the chrome console it said that I need popper but it run the project correctly

Comment: probably shouldn't ignore an error though, it might come up again later on in the project and you might spend a lot of time trying to find what it is exactly that's wrong - the way I undersand it, popper is an external framework bootstrap is using to create popups....
Good luck! 
Oh and try to edit your question or answer it and mark the question as resolved to help others who get the same problem in the future :)